# Visual Studio 2012/13 preset?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvm, command

i would like to configure visual studio, that every time i open a new project, some standard folder and classes also will be created.

that means, when i open a new project folder like Commands, ViewModel, Model, View are in this new project, so i do not have to create these.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. What you are looking for is [Project templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247120%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can find more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xkh1wxd8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @user2996927: if answer is what you looking for please be kind and accept it. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the Button. (new here)